# Reference globally-scope variable with same local-scope variable name in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I'm just starting with Node JS and I was wondering if the next is possible:

```
var a = 'A1';

function foo(a) {
    console.log(`${a}, ${a}`);
}

foo('A2');
```

This will print "A2, A2", is there a way I can get "A1, A2"?

Comment: Since you've tagged this node.js, the first `a` is not global.  It's a module-scoped variable which is technically just a local variable in a higher scope. If it was global and was declared as such, you could reference it as `global.a`, but not as you've declared it here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the correction, as I told you, I'm still getting familiar with the concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged this `node.js`, your first `a` is not global - it's just a higher scoped module variable which is actually a local variable in the module function wrapper.  So, it's just a higher scoped variable.

The local `a` shadows and hides the higher scoped `a`.  There is no way to get to the higher scoped `a` as you have it unless it is actually global (which it isn't here).  You would have to either change the name of one of them or put one of them into an object so you could reference them through the object rather than as a direct variable reference.

When resolving a variable reference in Javascript, the interpreter uses a hierarchical lookup.  First, it looks in the local scope object to see if the variable is in that scope.  If it is, it grabs the value and is done looking for it.  If it is not found in the local scope (and only if it is not found in the local scope object), then it goes up to the next higher scope object and looks there.  If the symbol name is found in the local scope, it will not look in a higher scope and there is no way to directly reference a higher scope unless the variable is not just a naked variable, but is inside of some object and you can reference the property on that object rather than the variable directly.

So,  you could do this:

```
var parms = {a: 'A1'};

function foo(a) {
    console.log(`${parms.a}, ${a}`);
}

foo('A2');
```

Or, of course you could change the names:

```
var a = 'A1';

function foo(b) {
    console.log(`${a}, ${b}`);
}

foo('A2');
```

Comment: Technically correct of course, but as is very evident by my answer, I find this kind of code unworthy of a "solution"...

Comment: @Amit - As my answer clearly explains, there is NO way to directly reference a shadowed variable in a higher scope.  That's the answer.  I just offered a few alternatives to solve the problem another way since it can't be done the way the OP has the code.

Comment: @Amit - Also, your answer seems to think the first `a` is global.  Since this is node.js, that's a module and that first `a` is a module variable, not a global.